# Error in Rock Paper Scissors program

Tags: java

The original prompt had us making a rock paper scissors game I think my code should work so far but I am getting the error "cannot find symbol" in line 64 when I try to track if a tie happens. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class RPS
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
           Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           Random myRandom = new Random();
           boolean n = false;
           System.out.println("Welcome to the Rock, Paper, Scissors game!!");
           System.out.println("When you play, your choices are rock, paper, or     scissors");       
           do
           {
            int compChoice = myRandom.nextInt(3);
            String rock = "0";
            String paper = "1";
            String scissors = "2";
            Integer.parseInt(rock);
            Integer.parseInt(paper);
            Integer.parseInt(scissors);
            int compWins = 0;
            int humanWins = 0;
            int ties = 0;
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            int choice = Integer.parseInt(myScanner.nextLine());
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {  
                if(choice == 0 && compChoice == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("I choose paper: I win this turn");
                    i++;
                    compWins++;
                } else if(choice == 0 && compChoice == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("I choose scissors: You win this turn");
                    i++;
                    humanWins++;
                } else if(choice == 1 && compChoice == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("I choose rock: You win this turn");
                    i++;
                    humanWins++;
                }   else if(choice == 1 && compChoice == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("I choose scissors: I win this turn");
                    i++;
                    compWins++;
                } else if(choice == 2 && compChoice == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("I choose rock: I win this turn");
                    i++;
                    compWins++;
                } else if(choice == 2 && compChoice == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("I choose paper: You win this turn");
                    i++;
                    humanWins++;
                } else if(choice == compchoice)
                {
                    System.out.println("This round is a tie");
                    i++;
                    ties++;
                }    
                System.out.println("Score: me: " + compWins + "you: " + humanWins +  "ties: " + ties);
            }  
                if(compWins > humanWins)
                {
                    System.out.println("Game over: I win!");
                } else if(humanWins > compWins)
                {
                    System.out.println("Game over: You win!");
                }else
                    System.out.println("Game over: No one wins!");
            System.out.print("Play again? (y/n)");
            String ending = myScanner.nextLine();
            if(ending == n)
            {
                n = true;
            }   
           }
           while(!n);
           System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
           System.exit(0);
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Do you want us to count to 64?

Comment: `compchoice` vs `compChoice`. Just check your spelling for typos. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Java is case sinsitive, when you declared a variable you have to stick with that declaration.

So try to change :

```
} else if(choice == compChoice) // here you need to change compchoice to compChoice
            {
                System.out.println("This round is a tie");
                i++;
                ties++;
            }    
            System.out.println("Score: me: " + compWins + "you: " + humanWins +  "ties: " + ties);
```

Also You comparing a String with boolean, you need to parse the String to boolean then compare:

```
boolean ending = Boolean.valueOf(myScanner.nextLine());
        if(ending == n)
        {
            n = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`compchoice` is not camel case. You declared it as `compChoice`.

Comment: Also, the comparison ending == n is between different types. You should be using an IDE like eclipse, or any other that could highlight you these compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors:

- Java is case-sensitive, and you are using `compchoice` which is not declared anywhere. I guess you wanted to use `compChoice` instead:

  ```
  } else if (choice == compChoice) {
  ```
- You are comparing a `String` with a `boolean` in the line

  ```
  if (ending == n) {
  ```

  which *is not a valid comparison* because they are from different types. You may want to check your logic there.

Comment: if(ending.equals(y)) n=true;